# Open Gallery to a Self Generated Folder

Tags: android

I want to open the default gallery app to a folder (named fooo) in the primary storage. I thought the easiest way would be to use Intents. When I use this code for my intent, the gallery app opens but it shows no image. I check with file explorer and there are images.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/fooo/");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no requirement for any `ACTION_VIEW` activity to be able to handle a directory as the `Uri`.

Second, your MIME type is incorrect, as a directory is not an image.

Third, your `Uri` is invalid, because it lacks a scheme. Replace:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/fooo/");
```

with:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "fooo");
```

Comment: how about this? https://pastebin.com/NymC5Yyj but it still does not work. My apologies, please help...

Comment: @PeterStewart: As I wrote, there is no requirement for any `ACTION_VIEW` activity to be able to handle a directory as the `Uri`.